# Migrating from Subversion to Git how can I find a commit given a revision number?

Tags: svn, git, migration, git-svn

Migrating from Subversion to Git using svn2git (which internally uses git-svn) I'd like to know how I can find a specific revision commit.

It is quite common to have issues tracker to have comments like:
"Fixed in r12345".

Given this, I'd like to be able, for example, to extract the diff corresponding to r12345.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given the revision number, you can find the Git SHA with

```
git svn find-rev r1938
```

I don't know if there's a "one-shot" way to get the commit or anything, but you can write something like

```
git log -p `git svn find-rev r1938`
```

---

Update: note that you can also grab the commit message with

```
git svn log -r 1938
```

---

Update again: note that `find-rev` also works in reverse:

```
git svn find-rev c7443021942
```

returns the SVN commit number.

Comment: This is working on the repository which has been used for the migration. If this repository is going remote, it cannot be used anymore, however it is still possible to get it using: `git log --grep='@12345'`. Can you update your answer with this too?

Comment: I think your comment is good enough `:)` I'm not really sure what you mean by "going remote" so I can't help too much more, sorry.

Comment: I mean: if you push the local repository to a remote one. Then only the `git log` method will work.

Answer (score -2):

With Git it’s similar:

```
Fixed in d8602bb9729ddb2f28e61028cc5981cb310231a2.
```

Get the diff with:

```
git show d8602bb9729ddb2f28e61028cc5981cb310231a2
```

Comment: note that you typically only need the first five or so characters of the hash

Comment: It doesn't tell me at all how I can figure out that svn commit 12345 has been mapped to commit ID: d8602bb9729ddb2f28e61028cc5981cb310231a2 after the migration!
Basically I need something like:
git show -r12345

Comment: You can use `git log -1` to show the commit ID of the latest commit. Feed that ID to `git show`, voilá. To find a specific svn revision in a repository, try `git log --grep=‘@12345’ -p`.