# How to revert multiple revisions with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I need to revert multiple revisions (e.g. 28693, 28756, 28747) which are already in svn repo.

With svn I can achieve this with one command:

```
svn merge -c -28693,-28756,-28747 https://repository/trunk
```

How to make the same with git-svn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git revert <commit1> <commit2> ...` should do the trick.

**Edit** following the discussion:
If you don't know the hashes (you can find the SVN revisions in the `git log` by looking at the `git-svn-id` field, it's the number after the `@`), the following one-liner works for me:

```
git revert $(echo r<REV1> r<REV2> r<REV3> | xargs -n1 git svn find-rev)
```

Comment: This will revert range of commits (28693-28747), not cherry-picked revisions (28693, 28756, 28747).

Comment: Also, you've omitted the step where you need to figure out which `git` commits correspond to the desired revisions. I'm unaware of a simpler way to do that than manually scanning commit messages for `git-svn-id`s that contain the revision numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just didn't wanted to ask to many questions at once:) Answer for any of them would be big step forward. If none will be possible then, well some shell script will do the thing.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. specifying the commits individually such as `git revert <commit1> <commit2> <commit3>` also works. The problem of mapping SVN revision numbers to commit hashes remains, though.

Comment: @chepner: On finding a Git hash from a Subversion revision number: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2989825/220155